# material ui does not show default colors and shapes when compiled on android

Tags: flutter, flutter-material

I deleted the `android` folder and recreate it via `flutter create --platforms android .`.
It compiles and runs, but the material components are showed incorrectly (no default blue, shape etc):

As you can see, for instance, the :

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Acceso'))
```

is showed with a white background, and the `ElevatedButtton` is showed rounded and with purple colors.

The widgets are  wrapped within a:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'App name',
        // initialRoute: ,
        navigatorKey: _navigator,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
```

so I was expecting a blue color at least. What could be missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter has changed its default theme blue color to purple and some of its widgets(if you set `useMaterial3: true` in **ThemeData** )

After editing your question, there are 2 ways,
To change app theme color you need to add

```
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.blue),
```

inside your **ThemeData**

if you create a new project with Flutter version 3.16.9,
your Material app looks like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
    useMaterial3: true,
  ),
  home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
);
  }
  }
```

the second way is only changing AppBar,
You need to add `appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.blue),` in *MaterialApp/theme*

For Example:

```
MaterialApp(
    title: 'App name',
    // initialRoute: ,
    navigatorKey: _navigator,
    theme: ThemeData(
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(  //Add here
        color: Colors.blue
      ),                        // until here
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
);
```

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: That only partially fix the problem: apparently, the default rendering is not there for any component. Look at the button for instance: colors apart, the shape is not the matirialUI's default one. Without touching the code, the default theme has disappeared. What could have happened?

Comment: flutter has changed its default theme from blue to purple and its shapes. If you create  a new flutter project, the material code looks like this    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );

Comment: @Bertuz I Updated my answer, check it out please

Answer (score 0):

New Flutter versions use `colorScheme` instead `primarySwatch`.

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'App name',
        // initialRoute: ,
        navigatorKey: _navigator,
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.blue),
        ),
```